# Perl sorting; dealing with $a, $b package globals across namespaces cleanly

Tags: perl, sorting, namespaces

Suppose I have a utility library (`other`) containing a subroutine 
(`sort_it`) which I want to use to return arbitrarily sorted data.
It's probably more complicated than this, but this illustrates the 
key concepts:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;

package other;

sub sort_it {
  my($data, $sort_function) = @_;

  return([sort $sort_function @$data]);
}
```

Now let's use it in another package.

```
package main;
use Data::Dumper;

my($data) = [
        {'animal' => 'bird',            'legs' => 2},
        {'animal' => 'black widow',     'legs' => 8},
        {'animal' => 'dog',             'legs' => 4},
        {'animal' => 'grasshopper',     'legs' => 6},
        {'animal' => 'human',           'legs' => 2},
        {'animal' => 'mosquito',        'legs' => 6},
        {'animal' => 'rhino',           'legs' => 4},
        {'animal' => 'tarantula',       'legs' => 8},
        {'animal' => 'tiger',           'legs' => 4},
        ],

my($sort_by_legs_then_name) = sub {
    return ($a->{'legs'}   <=> $b->{'legs'} ||
            $a->{'animal'} cmp $b->{'animal'});
};

print Dumper(other::sort_it($data, $sort_by_legs_then_name));
```

This doesn't work, due to a subtle problem.  `$a` and `$b` are package
globals.  They refer to `$main::a` and `$main::b` when wrapped up in 
the closure.

We could fix this by saying, instead:

```
my($sort_by_legs_then_name) = sub {
    return ($other::a->{'legs'}   <=> $other::b->{'legs'} ||
            $other::a->{'animal'} cmp $other::b->{'animal'});
};
```

This works, but forces us to hardcode the name of our utility package
everywhere.  Were that to change, we'd need to remember to change the
code, not just the `use other qw(sort_it);` statement that would likely
be present in the real world.

You might immediately think to try using `__PACKAGE__`.  That winds 
up evaluating to "main".  So does `eval("__PACKAGE__");`.

There's a trick using [`caller`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) that works:

```
my($sort_by_legs_then_name) = sub {
  my($context) = [caller(0)]->[0];
  my($a) = eval("\$$context" . "::a");
  my($b) = eval("\$$context" . "::b");

  return ($a->{'legs'}   <=> $b->{'legs'} ||
          $a->{'animal'} cmp $b->{'animal'});
};
```

But this is rather black-magical.  It seems like there ought to be
some better solution to this.  But I haven't found it or figured it 
out yet.

Comment: If you use caller like that, won't it break just as much if the package that defined the sub and the package that call other::sort_it are different?

Answer (score 9):

Use the prototype (solution originally proposed in [Usenet posting](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.perl.moderated/browse_thread/thread/92a7291dd200fde5/d9a65a6b01a21d04?#d9a65a6b01a21d04) by [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth)).

Works on Perl >= 5.10.1 (not sure about earlier).

```
my($sort_by_legs_then_name) = sub ($$) {
    my ($a1,$b1) = @_;
    return ( $a1->{'legs'} <=> $b1->{'legs'} ||
            $a1->{'animal'} cmp $b1->{'animal'});
};
```

I get as a result:

```
$VAR1 = [
      {
        'legs' => 2,
        'animal' => 'bird'
      },
      {
        'legs' => 2,
        'animal' => 'human'
      },
      {
        'legs' => 4,
        'animal' => 'dog'
      },
      {
        'legs' => 4,
        'animal' => 'rhino'
      },
      {
        'legs' => 4,
        'animal' => 'tiger'
      },
      {
        'legs' => 6,
        'animal' => 'grasshopper'
      },
      {
        'legs' => 6,
        'animal' => 'mosquito'
      },
      {
        'legs' => 8,
        'animal' => 'black widow'
      },
      {
        'legs' => 8,
        'animal' => 'tarantula'
      }
    ];
```

Comment: I wonder if Perl6::Placeholders would work as well? (http://search.cpan.org/~lpalmer/Perl6-Placeholders-0.07/lib/Perl6/Placeholders.pm)

Comment: The change was made in [Perl 5.6](http://search.cpan.org/~gsar/perl-5.6.0/pod/perldelta.pod#Enhanced_support_for_sort%28%29_subroutines).  There is a [documented performance penalty](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) for doing it though.

Comment: The performance penalty is not that bad in comparison to using an anonymous subroutine, but both are significantly slower than using a block: http://gist.github.com/603932 This is one senario where abstraction might not be your friend.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sub sort_it {
  my($data, $sort_function) = @_;
  my($context) = [caller(0)]->[0];
  no strict 'refs';
  local *a = "${context}::a";
  local *b = "${context}::b";
  return([sort $sort_function @$data]);
}
```

And you will not pay overhead in each call.

But I would prefer

```
sub sort_it (&@) {
  my $sort_function = shift;
  my($context) = [caller(0)]->[0];
  no strict 'refs';
  local *a = "${context}::a";
  local *b = "${context}::b";
  return([sort $sort_function @_]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it:

```
sub sort_it {
    my ($data, $sort) = @_;
    my $caller = caller;
    eval "package $caller;"    # enter caller's package
       . '[sort $sort @$data]' # sort at full speed
      or die $@                # rethrow any errors
}
```

`eval` is needed here because `package` only takes a bare package name, not a variable.