# Trying to custom-sort a phylogenetic tree in BioPerl results in "undefined value" or "unblessed reference" error

Tags: perl, sorting, namespaces, bioperl

I have a phylogenetic tree I am loading in BioPerl. I want to use a custom sort function ("$depth_sort" below) to order the nodes vertically when printing out the tree. However the documented method used below writes out the tree in the same order it was read in, without actually sorting:

```
use strict;
use Bio::TreeIO;

my $input = new Bio::TreeIO(-file=>"input.tree", -format=>'newick');
my $tree = $input->next_tree;

my $depth_sort = sub { $a->depth <=> $b->depth };

#this is the way it is supposed to work:
my $out = new Bio::TreeIO(
     -file     => ">sorted.tree", 
     -format   => 'newick', 
     -order_by => $depth_sort
);
$out->write_tree($tree);
```

Instead, I can manually iterate through the tree to see what is happening. If I do my own sort locally, it works as expected:

```
my $rnode = $tree->get_root_node;
&printNode($rnode);

sub printNode {
    my $thisNode = shift;

    #print the node identity and depth, just to keep track:
    print "this is " . $thisNode->internal_id . 
          " with depth " . $thisNode->depth . "\n";

    if (! $thisNode->is_Leaf) {
        my @children = sort $depth_sort $thisNode->each_Descendent();
        for my $otherNode (@children) { &printNode($otherNode); }
    }
}
```

But, if I pass the custom sort to each_Descendent (the way the write call above is supposed to):

```
my @children = $thisNode->each_Descendent($depth_sort);
```

Then it dies with the message:

> Can't call method "depth" on an undefined value at treeFlipper.pl line
>   7,  line 1.

I found another thread here that I think has me on the right track, but I haven't solved it yet: [Perl sorting; dealing with $a, $b package globals across namespaces cleanly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826978/perl-sorting-dealing-with-a-b-package-globals-across-namespaces-cleanly)

Switching to the prototyping method in the first answer:

```
my $depth_sort = sub ($$) { 
    my ($a1,$b1) = @_;
    return ($a1->depth <=> $b1->depth) };
```

gives me:

> Can't call method "depth" on unblessed reference at treeFlipper.pl
>   line 9,  line 1.

But if I check the ref type, that seems correct:

```
print ref($a1) . "\n";
```

gives

```
Bio::Tree::Node
```

When I try force-blessing the reference (this is probably a terrible thing to do):

```
bless $a1, 'Bio::Tree::Node';
bless $b1, 'Bio::Tree::Node';
```

I get:

> Not a HASH reference at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Bio/Tree/Node.pm line 433,  line 1.

The other methods in that thread (using caller) give me the same old "undefined value" error.

Is this a problem with BioPerl, or (as I suspect) am I still missing something? Thanks!

edit: using Perl 5.14.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: What does your documentation say about the custom sort? I can't seem to find any documentation on cpan.

Comment: I reinstalled BioPerl and now it seems to work, at least manually. Bio::TreeIO::write() is still ignoring the sort command, but that is clearly a BioPerl problem that I will ask there.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~cjfields/BioPerl-1.6.901/Bio/TreeIO/newick.pm#new
This is not the direct call, but the Bio::TreeIO::new() function is supposed to pass additional args along to the constructor for the specific format:
<code>$obj = "Bio::TreeIO::$format"->new(@args);</code>

Comment: And I solved that last issue by manually invoking
<code>$out->get_params->{'order_by'}=$depth_sort;</code>
in between the initialization and the actual writing. I can't close this question, though, since I'm a n00b...

Comment: You can answer your own question. Write down what you did to solve your problem and accept it. It may be of use for someone else later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There turned out to be three parts to this:

1. The sort function does need to be prototyped and indexed directly OR accessed through the calling package, as documented (for instance) in the other thread I linked to.
2. Why it still didn't work after fixing the sort function is a bit of a mystery, but is probably non-reproducible. It was solved by reinstalling BioPerl.
3. Finally, it turns out that the current version of BioPerl (I have 1.6.9) doesn't fully implement the "order_by" parameter --the Bio::TreeIO::newick constructor does not set the passed-in value like it should. However, I was able to get around this by explicitly setting the parameter *after* construction:

   ```
   my $out = new Bio::TreeIO(
        -file     => ">sorted.tree", 
        -format   => 'newick', 
   );
   $out->get_params->{'order_by'}=$depth_sort;
   $out->write_tree($tree);
   ```

This worked as expected.